# MVC 5 The type exists in both

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, resx

I'm upgrading my application and making int multilingual - I use .resx files for that purpose but I encountered a problem. Everything works fine when I use culture info to determine which display name should be used for current request (annotations in models); but when I just want to display the text (in view), it doesn't work, I get following error:

```
The type 'Language' exists in both
'TradeGlobe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
and
'App_GlobalResources.ulzrrip3, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

The way I'm trying to do it in my view:

```
@Resources.Language.requiredError
```

where Language is the name of my .resx files and its namespace. I have no idea what App_GlobalResources.ulzrrip3 is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to Clean your build, empty your `bin` directory, and build it again.

Comment: I tried it before posting. No luck.

Comment: Check your package.config. May be the recent references causing this issue. Try to step back and see what you have added.

Comment: Hmm... There are no recent changes in references. So that's not the issue as well.

Comment: Simply, the type `Language` exists in multiple referenced namespaces, and your application is unable to determine which of the two is the `Language` you want to use here. Apparently, even prefixing `Resources` as you have is not enough to remove the ambiguity. Long and short, reference the exact namespace, and you should be good. For example: `TradeGlobe.Resources.Language`. (That may not be correct; it's just for illustration).